# When using the jQuery BBQ plugin, is there a way to make the getState() method ignore case?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-bbq

I am using the jQuery BBQ plugin:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

It has been pretty awesome, however when calling `$.bbq.getState();` case seems to be important.

*For instance, consider the following URL: `http://mysite.com/#someVar=someValue`.*

If I call `$.bbq.getState('someVar');` I am able to retrieve the value of the query string variable, but if I call `$.bbq.getState('somevar');` **(with a lowercase v)** the value is `undefined`.

I can build the URL using a constant value that will always write it in the correct case, but I am thinking of the scenario where a user may type the URL out.  If they type the wrong case, the `$.bbq.getState()` method will tell me that the 'someVar' value is not part of the URL.

So I am wondering ... **Is there a way to tell `$.bbq.getState()` to be case insensitive?**

Comment: You probably want to use lowercase names for URL params to start with.